# FATAL_ERROR when running 'pocketsphinx_continuous' on WAV file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I meet a error code such as below

```
FATAL_ERROR: "acmod.c", line 409: Decoder can not process more than 32767 frames at once, requested 32768
```

The same problem was appeared and solved.

http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/f609780c/
http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/c8b7d2be/?limit=25#8b63

But I can't even find such a file or directory "pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx/hmm.h"

I am currently using MacOSX 10.11 and have installed pocketsphinx using "brew install cmu-pocketsphinx"

Does anyone solve or encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Install pocketsphinx from source

Comment: Usually answers on SO contain a few more details. To me this looks more like a comment.